# Hide secret from the webchat iframe

Tags: asp.net, botframework

My bot is running in an iframe, but I want to hide the secret.
Is it possible to use the iframe and hide the secret from the users?

Comment: Did my answer below solve your question?

Comment: No, it´s still accessable althought they can´t change anything with that

Comment: What kind of ASP.NET page are you embedding on? Webforms, MVC, Razor? If you do the request for the token using your secret in the code behind then pass the token to the view then users will not be able to see the secret.

Comment: I let the key public, because of time and although users can see it they can not change anything with that.
Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

See option one [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#embed-the-web-chat-control-in-your-website) but instead of doing the request to get the token on the client side you could do it on the server side when the page loads then pass it through to the client side. That way you only expose the temporary token to anyone inspecting your iframe code.

Using ASP.NET this could be achieved inside the Page_Load event writing to a hidden field if you’re using webforms, Index/Get method of the controller writing to a bound property and hidden field if you’re using mvc, or in the OnGet method and set on the model of a Razor page.

There are various ways you could do the HTTP request - using the built in WebRequest or HttpClient classes, or using a third party library such as RestSharp.